Avoid url normalization in a nginx reverse proxy
I am in K8S and I have configured a nginx in reverse proxy so that calls to /api/img are redirected to my service.
Example /api/img/123%2F456/123.png -> http://service/123%2F456/123.png
The configuration is as follows:
location /api/img {
   proxy_pass http://service/;
}

However, on my service I get the following url : http://service/123/456/123.png
How to avoid this ?
I have tried the following configurations (without success)
      location /api/img {
        rewrite ^/api/img(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://service;
      }

-> http://service/123/456/123.png
      location /api/img {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/api/img(/.*) $1 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://service;
      }

-> no resolver defined to resolve service
  location /api/img {
    rewrite ^ $request_uri;
    rewrite ^/test(/.*) $1 break;
    return 400;
    proxy_pass http://service$uri;
  }

-> no resolver defined to resolve service
I don't want to define a resolver, because my configuration must be applied on any k8s cluster.

TBH the problem is your service which is treating / and %2F differently, which according to URL rules are identical.

Actually %2F is a part of a base64 value, that's why I treat / and %2F.

Rightly or wrongly Nginx normalises the %2F before allowing it to be processed by rewrite. The only solution that appears to proxy_pass the modified URL correctly, unfortunately also requires a resolver.
